# Cannot INSERT the following data into MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

im trying to insert the following data into the Table in MSSQL.

```
(1, 'Tony', NULL ,1.81, 65.43, 0, '1957-05-10', NULL),
(2, 'Mark', NULL ,1.81, 65.43, 0, '1957-05-10', NULL),
(3, 'Tanya', 5 ,1.81, 65.43, 1, '1957-05-10', NULL),
(4, 'Марк', NULL ,1.81, 65.43, 0, '1957-05-10','Dura bura'),
(5, 'Toncho', 2 ,1.81, 65.43, 0, '1957-05-10','Сто чадъра')
```

Unfortunately I get 'Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric' and I have no idea why. Here is the code and I just cannot understand why it doesn't work. I tried reading other posts, but I am just starting and I cannot understand most of what is written in the other problem/suggestions :(

```
   CREATE DATABASE Human
USE Human
CREATE TABLE People
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    Picture VARBINARY(MAX),
    Height DECIMAL(5,2),
    [Weight] DECIMAL(5,2),
    Gender BIT NOT NULL,
    Birthdate DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Biography NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
INSERT INTO People(Id, [Name], Picture, Height, [Weight], Gender, Birthdate, Biography) VALUES
    (1, 'Tony', NULL ,1.81, 65.43, 0, '1957-05-10', NULL),
    (2, 'Mark', NULL ,1.81, 65.43, 0, '1957-05-10', NULL),
    (3, 'Tanya', 5 ,1.81, 65.43, 1, '1957-05-10', NULL),
    (4, 'Марк', NULL ,1.81, 65.43, 0, '1957-05-10','Dura bura'),
    (5, 'Toncho', 2 ,1.81, 65.43, 0, '1957-05-10','Сто чадъра')
```

Comment: [Seems](https://rextester.com/KDI26469) to work fine. You do need to specify Unicode: `N'Сто чадъра'`

Comment: I can't repro your error. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6cd8b519b3abf3dd8869138fe87fde3d)

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this error with a number, that does not fit in `numeric(5,2)` data type  (e.g. `(1, 'Tony', NULL , 1111.81, 65.43, 0, '1957-05-10', NULL)`). But with the data from the question the statement is execvuted without an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you experiencing this problem with provided statement/data or is the statment/data an example and not 1:1?

Works for me.
[image: Example]

Som maybe some DB/sErver setting that i cant think of of my head.

1. try to identify row, do a row by row insert, try only 1, only 2 ... only 5, to identify which row(s)
2. remove columns to check which one it is

is this the exact data you get the error on? my guess would be you have a numeric value for height or weight thats more then 999.99. Maybe missing decimal dot for weight?

Comment: This is the exact data. It is supposed to be a starting problem and im already a few hours into researching on how to fix it :/

Comment: @NikolaKapralov best quess is PEBKAC, no insult intended but some missing detail, like extra 0, missing . or something like that. Just to be sure, could you provide a screenshot like i did? of the code you run?

Comment: @NikolaKapralov no, please don't provide a screenshot of code like asked here; it's really not helpful for others. The way you did in your question is by far the best way as we can both consume and run it ourselves.

Comment: I will update my answer with the exact code. I do believe it is my error, I would just like to know what I did wrong in order to not replicate it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I believe I had some leftovers in the DB or somewhere else that I had not cleared and it was interfering with the code. Restarting the program, deleting everything(i had to delete the DB too or it just happened to work when I did), reconnecting and writing it from scratch solved this issue.
Exact code as per request. I was running only the INSERT part when I received the issue. I cannot seem to run the whole code in one go, I must execute it line by line even if no such DB exists.

```
CREATE DATABASE Human
USE Human
CREATE TABLE People
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    Picture VARBINARY(MAX),
    Height DECIMAL(5,2),
    [Weight] DECIMAL(5,2),
    Gender BIT NOT NULL,
    Birthdate DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Biography NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
INSERT INTO People(Id, [Name], Picture, Height, [Weight], Gender, Birthdate, Biography) VALUES
    (1, 'Tony', NULL ,1.81, 65.43, 0, '1957-05-10', NULL),
    (2, 'Mark', NULL ,1.81, 65.43, 0, '1957-05-10', NULL),
    (3, 'Tanya', 5 ,1.81, 65.43, 1, '1957-05-10', NULL),
    (4, 'Марк', NULL ,1.81, 65.43, 0, '1957-05-10','Dura bura'),
    (5, 'Toncho', 2 ,1.81, 65.43, 0, '1957-05-10','Сто чадъра')
```

Comment: with you dropping the db, we an only guess. if dropping db helped, then best guess would be one of the decimal columns (height,weight) had different size specified